# iOS 9 monospace text

Tags: ios

I have a date countdown in my app in which I'd like to make use of San Francisco's monospaced number feature. I currently retrieve the font using this code:

```
UIFontDescriptor *countdownFontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
NSArray *additionalFontSettings = @[@{UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberSpacingType), UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kMonospacedNumbersSelector)},
                                    @{UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kTextSpacingType), UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kMonospacedTextSelector)}];
countdownFontDescriptor = [countdownFontDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes: @{UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: additionalFontSettings}];
UIFont *desiredFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:countdownFontDescriptor size:14];
```

I get monospaced numbers as they should appear, but I have semicolons in my string which separate the numbers. Occasionally I see this character move. How can I get the width of the semicolon to remain constant also? (This is why I tried adding `kTextSpacingType`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but did you try looking in (as of Xcode 9.1 beta)

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/SFNTLayoutTypes.h.
```

I can't see a way to do it there, but maybe someone else can.